# setInterval not running every second

Tags: javascript, react-native, setinterval

I'm using setInterval in react-native as below with the TimerMixin.

```
TimerMixin.setInterval(
  () => {
      console.log('timer running!');
      const seconds = this.gameTimerView.current.returnSeconds();
      console.log(`timer seconds: ${seconds}`);
    },
  1000
);
```

I notice from the logs that it does not get called every second.

```
.js:1648 timer seconds: 6
.js:1646 timer running!
.js:1648 timer seconds: 7
.js:1646 timer running!
.js:1648 timer seconds: 8
.js:1646 timer running!
.js:1648 timer seconds: 10
.js:1646 timer running!
```

Is there anyway I can ensure this is run every single second?

// UPDATE
The root of this is that we have an object/array of values such as:

```
{ 
    0: {positionSpace: 0, completed: false },
    7: {positionSpace: 7, completed: false },
    12: {positionSpace: 8, completed: false },
    20: {positionSpace: 14, completed: false },
}
```

For every key value in the above, we need to move a user/small animation. I.e. At 7 seconds, then 12 seconds, then 20 seconds and so on.

However, the important note here is that the timer can be paused. I.e. If the user closes the app (pauses) the timer is paused too. So we couldn't just `setTimeout` for each of the above as wouldn't think this would work?

Comment: It runs roughly every second if the cpu load and the workload of the js engine allows it to. You can never guarantee that a script will run every second, so if timing is important then you normally calculate the elapsed time since the last calculation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part of your comment, please?

Comment: Depends what you want todo. If you need it for an animation you need to calculate the elapsed time in a higher accuracy then seconds since the last animation step. If you want to display a countdown/elapsed timer, then you need to do something else.

Comment: I will update the question with the route/scene here.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that the shift is making that big gap. It might be caused by the components you are using.

But from javascript core point of view, it is impossible to be sure that the time does not drift - even if you find the cause of that big time drift.

- https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/
- https://johnresig.com/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: Thats not a huge gap. More likely something like  `8.4...` seconds and `9.8...` seconds.